# Show div when accordion is open

Tags: accordion

i have a jquery accordion content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.question').click(function() {
        $('div.answer').slideUp(600);   
        $(this).next().slideDown(600);
    });
    $("div.answer").hide();
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="question">Question</div>
<div class="answer">Answer</div>
```

i need to show another div when my accordion is open. i don't wanna use div with answer class.
i need to make another div with different class. i know i cane use 2 different class in div like this:

```
class="answer anotherclass"
```

but i cant make my template nice this way!

**Example:**

```
<div class="question">Question</div>
<div class="hide">Hide Contents</div>
<div class="answer">Answer</div>
```

i want to hide second div when my answer div is close. then after click on question, i need to  show hide div and answer div. i cant put my hide div in answer div. something like fade in effect for hide div.

i hope u guys understand my question.

**EDIT:**
i need somthing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('div.question').click(function() {
$('div.another').fadeIn(600);
$(this).next().fadeOut(600);
$('div.answer').slideUp(600);   
$(this).next().slideDown(600);
});

$("div.answer").hide();
$("div.another").hide();    
});
```

**HTML:**
    Question
    Answer
    Another
but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You could place the hide div inside you question div and simply show/hide it when the question is clicked. Probably best to use jQuery toggle for that.

Comment: thanks, but i think i need to fade in effect with a another div when i click on my question link.

Comment: Cool, so you just use jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() instead of show() and hide().

Comment: Ok, listen my friend! when i click on question, i want to show 2 different div, one with accordion one with fade in effect! i CANT use your way!